# $f: \mathbb Z \to [0,1), z \mapsto \theta z - \lfloor \theta z \rfloor , \overline{ f(\mathbb Z) } = [0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We have a function $f: \mathbb Z \to [0,1), z \mapsto \theta z - \lfloor \theta z \rfloor , \theta \in \mathbb R , \theta \notin  \mathbb Q$. The function is clearly injective and $f(\mathbb Z) \cap \mathbb Q = \emptyset$.

I need to show that $ \overline{ f(\mathbb Z) } = [0,1)$.

I take a point from $x \in [0,1)$ and $\epsilon >0$, and try to show that in $(x-\epsilon, x + \epsilon)$ there is a point from $f(\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: Hint: Use the pigeonhole principle to show that for every $n$ there are some $f(k)$ and $f(j)$ at distance at most $\frac1n$, then deduce that every $x$ in $[0,1)$ is at distance at most $\frac1n$ from $f(\mathbb Z)$, then conclude.

Comment: ((As an aside, note that I view the last sentence of your post as a typical example of *fake* personal input. What did you really try to solve this?))